# Is there any news feed (event/activity stream) engine?

Tags: scalability, feed

I'm looking for an open source news feed engine to use in an app I'm developing.

The engine needs to be able to aggregate news (items) from multiple sources a user is following and also optionally group them by news source or news type. A scalable solution in Java or with Java interface would be great.

I have already developed a very simple one, but I would prefer to use a robust and reliable solution instead.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I created a backend for this in Java builing on neo4j: It is independent on the number of users and news sources one follows but depends just linear on the amount of items you want to display

find an explaination how it works and benchmarks with social networks with up to 2 mio users at http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/graphity-an-efficient-graph-model-for-retrieving-the-top-k-news-feeds-for-users-in-social-networks/

There is also the source code available: https://github.com/renepickhardt/graphity-evaluation

Answer (score 1):

Check out Rome
http://rometools.org/

In case you also use .NET, Argotic Syndication Framework is for sure the best
http://argotic.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[**Yahoo pipes**](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) is a very good rss feed which lets you create your own feed aggregator with custom filters.
Note: Python version for Yahoo pipes [Pipe2py](https://github.com/ggaughan/pipe2py).

Aonther offering from yahoo is [Daper](http://open.dapper.net/).

There are few more [online tools](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/10-tools-to-combine-mix-blend-multiple-rss-feeds/) for creating custom feeds which you might want to look at.

Answer (score -1):

[FeedDistiller](http://www.feeddistiller.com/) is a free service for aggregating new feeds by subject,

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. He's looking for a feed engine, not an rss reader.